# Как узнать размер View элементов в адаптере?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть 2 View ImageVIew и TextView. getView getHeight возвращяет 0.

Как мне узнать размер ImageVIew и TextView в Адаптере RecyclerView.
Может есть слушатель какой - нибудь для BindView?

---

Или можете мне сказать как рассчитать размеры элементов в XML. через LayoutInflater. А уже после я бы запустил адаптер....

---

Это мой ужасный код

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

//        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.icon.getLayoutParams();
//        if ((position & 1) == 0) layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
//        else layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

        holder.icon.post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                final int imgW = holder.icon.getWidth();
                final int imgH = holder.icon.getHeight();

                holder.messageView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int txtH=holder.messageView.getLineHeight();

                        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(str[0]));
                        int lines=imgH/txtH;
                        ss.setSpan(new TextViewMarginSpan(imgW,lines), 0, ss.length(), 0);
                        holder.messageView.setText(ss);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

---

Хочу сделать вот так 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ладно всем спасибо. Думаю по другому дизайну сделаю тогда и все. Чо мучиться 2-3 дня)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если размер `View` указан в dp/sp/px то можете перевести их в пиксели. Если `View` во всю ширину экрана то берете ширину экрана минус маргины (если есть).

Если ширина указана с весом, к примеру 0.3, то делите ширину экрана на 100 и умножайте на 30.

В этих случаях лучше считать размеры в конструкторе адартере единожды

Если в вашем случае так сделать нельзя, то вот, на худой конец юзайте

```
view.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        int w = view.getWidth();
        int h = view.getHeight();
    }
});
```

Comment: Работает, но есть одна проблема. Когда я быстро прокручиваю список. То некоторые элементы не успевают отобразиться нормально.

Выше приложил код который исопльзовал с вашей помощю

Comment: Попробуйте переместить внутренний `post` наружу. И еще. Размеры какой `View` не высчитываются корректно? Видимо `getLineHeight` как-то по-другому надо получать)

Comment: Как раз наоборот. ImageVIew не успевают расчитыыватья

Comment: Еще попробуйте полученные размеры сохранять во внешние переменные адаптера :) А при их получении сначала проверять чтобы они были нулевыми `if(imgH == 0) {  imgH = img.getHeight(); }` так сказать, напролом :D

Comment: Ой, я столько натерпелся с адаптерами... Вы не поверите. Просто всегда как-то удавалось решить проблему расчетом `dp` и всякими другими хаками. Расскажите подробнее о вашем конкретном случае, разметку итема и прочее

Comment: Хочу сделать так как на картинке выше. С обтеканием в Андроид прямо беда. Делаю все через LeadingMarginSpan2. Блин в Ios там уже все в коробке пару методов и все.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63529/discussion-between-flippy-and-eranewgames).

Answer (score 1):

Узнать размер View можно только после того, как все элементы Layout сформированы. Для этого существует OnGlobalLayoutListener

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
             // view сформирован, можно получать размеры
            });
```

Comment: В адаптере это нормально будет для 30 элементов?:

Кстати в onBindViewHolder это не рабоает

Comment: Чем данный способ отличается от `view.post(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {}});` ?

Comment: У меня view.post() пару раз не срабатывал корректно. Приходилось лепить это

Comment: @Serodv, А ты в адаптере использовал его? так как treeObser у меня только 3 раза вызфывается и все. Хотя элементов куда больше

Comment: Мне надо было знать размер одного view в элементе списка, чтобы грамотно расположить второй. Вешал слушатель на первый item. Когда он отстреливался, фиксировал размеры в переменных класса и менял размеры уже созданных, ну а новые уже располагались правильно, так как размер уже известен.

Comment: @Serodv, Тоже самое и я хочу сделать только в Адаптере.  А addOnGlobalLayoutListener работает лишь 3 раза

Comment: В конце концов перед созданием списка можно установить какой-нибудь тестовый лэйаут, совпадающий по размерам со списком, подождать, пока он сформируется и будут готовые размеры. Скорее всего моргнёт экран, а может и нет, если например высота нулевая) Ну и запомнить где нибудь в Preferences размеры и больше не касаться этой темы

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте получать размеры через `LayoutParams` так:

```
int width = view.getLayoutParams().width;
```

Ещё можно вот так попробовать рассчитать размеры. Этот способ позволит получить размеры до отрисовки, синхронно:

```
textView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
int height = textView.getMeasuredHeight();
int width= textView.getMeasuredWidth();
```

Comment: в Адаптере? А куда его добавить

Comment: @EraNewGames, получение размеров `View` - это очень сложная задача уровня `Middle` разработчика с зп $2500+/мес. Засим объяснение всех нюансов просто не поместится в ответ. Вам надо уточнить в вопросе что именно вам нужно и какую задачу вы решаете. Вам надо привести код в вопросе. Иначе мы не сможем вам ответить в разумном объёме за разумное время.

Comment: Вот это я нарвался)). Вообщем я хочу обтекание текста сделать вокруг ImageView. Допустим в html это просто делается. 'align' и все дела)).

Начал гуглить нашел LeadingMarginSpan2. Но она какая то глючная. Чтобы она работала, надо в начале узнать размеры ImageVIew и TextVIew. Вот тут то я и ушел в себя на 3 дня=((

Comment: @EraNewGames, попробуйте код из обновления ответа

Comment: Работает, но размер Картинки ширина и высота почти в 2 раза больше.

Вот xml
`android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: @EraNewGames, возможно вы путаете `dp` и `px` размеры. На разных экранах разное кол-во пикселей для один и тех же значений `dp` получится. Вам надо выяснить какие именно значения вам нужны. Скорее всего именно `px`, кои и возвращает предложенный код.

Comment: Нет. UNSPECIFIED возвращяет значение будто я установить wrap wrap. Я даже проверил сейчас. Это не то. Неужели нету в Андроид Listener который бы после того как View готово вызвался бы и все дела

Answer (score 0):

Гораздо удобней использовать `post`

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               view.getWidth(); 
            }
        });
```

Только в своем примере замените на свой `view`. Размер расчитается ровно после того, как вьюшка будет сформирована на разметке

Comment: Тоже самое написал флипу. Для адаптера не подходит такой способ. Быстро прокручиваю список и некоорые элементы не успевают отобразиться